# Trying to match convenience store names / gas station names to their corporate parent

Tags: data-request, business

looking to map (for example) all the various Kroger brand store names to "Kroger", will appreciate any pointers to datasets and/or data scrubbing logic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your budget.
I'd assume you need free data.

A good start will be [Croctail](http://croctail.corpwatch.org/#cw_1047,cw_1047,2016), they also provide [API and bulk download](http://api.corpwatch.org/). Mind that the data there, cleaned and parsed from SEC EDGAR's filings maps a legal entity to another legal entity relationship - you'll see relationship between the different Kroger companies, which might in term be operating some local stores.

Alternatively, you can query Unigraph which incorporates data from various sources including SEC EDGAR. With [this query](http://try.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A%20%20subjects(property%3A%20%22us_sec_cik_id%22%2C%20identifier%3A%20%220000056873%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20uid%0A%20%20%20%20owned_by%20%40reverse%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20uid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label.en%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) you can get a list of all companies (not individual stores) owned by Kroger.

*Disclaimer: I'm building Unigraph, reach out for more information or API key*

---

If you can pay for the data, Factual will be a great choice, here's [what they have](https://www.factual.com/data/t/places#filters=%7B%22$and%22:[%7B%22country%22:%7B%22$eq%22:%22US%22%7D%7D]%7D&q=Kroger) on Kroger.

Answer (score 1):

See
https://www.redliondata.com/dataset/kroger-usa-locations/

they have store Names and lat/long...